SSL error: "Connection reset" when connecting to a database in RazorSQL
Seemingly sporadically, I am receiving the following error when attempting to connect to a database in to RazorSQL:
`ERROR: An error occurred while trying to make a connection to
the database:
JDBC URL:
jdbc:postgresql://XXX:5439/prod?tcpKeepAlive=true&ssl=true
SSL error: Connection reset
`
Sometimes, this error occurs and other times it does not; I cannot discern what is different when it does not error. When the error does occur, it persists for several hours. I am prompted for the following parameters when connecting:
Profile Name, Profile Folder, Login, Password, Driver Class, Driver Location, JDBC URL, Max Results per Query, Auto Commit, SQL Restrictions, Transaction Isolation, Connect at Startup, SSH Tunnel.
Since the error sometimes does not appear, I do not change any of the parameters when logging in since they do work at least sometimes. It is always the same login, password, JDBC URL, etc. I expect it to work everytime, however the same error sometimes persists.
